# How do i prevent circular type reference in typescript with redux and connect when using mapState function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I've been following the **official tutorial** on using redux with typescript [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component).

Everything works fine except when I need to specify the incoming props type to `Props` in mapState.

This is the type error I am having from typescript, which I assume this to mean a circular reference:

```
'connector' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

Below is the code from the tutorial except with `props: Props` added to `mapState`

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';

interface RootState {
  isOn: boolean;
}

const mapState = (
  state: RootState,
  props: Props // <-- ERROR CAUSED BY ADDING TYPE 'Props' TO 'props'
) => ({
  isOn: state.isOn,
});

const mapDispatch = {
  toggleOn: () => ({ type: 'TOGGLE_IS_ON' }),
};

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch);

// The inferred type will look like:
// {isOn: boolean, toggleOn: () => void}
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

interface Props extends PropsFromRedux {
  backgroundColor: string;
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }}>
    <button onClick={props.toggleOn}>
      Toggle is {props.isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
    </button>
  </div>
);

export default connector(MyComponent);
```

How do I fix this? Setting type from `Props` to `any` will lose all type information. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First of all, should this be fixed? If I understand your code right, you basically expect `Props` to have the field `isOn`, even though it's something that's only provided by `mapState`. Then you expect `mapState` to get the props with the `isOn` field that shouldn't exist at that point?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs The `Props` is expecting `backgroundColor` string. The `isOn` is from `RootState` that is passed to mapState. `mapState` is takes two argument types, `RootState` and `Props` (any incoming props from the original component). The official documents (non typescript) allows this. It's valid code to pass in those two arguments.

Comment: Still, your `Props` is defined as extending `PropsFromRedux`, which is where the circular dependency comes from. And my point still stands: `isOn` I think. It's very fishy that your `Props` extends the type it's being mapped to.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs what do you think is the proper way to do this? I need to pass the original `props` to mapState for additional logic.

Comment: You should properly split up your props. One clear interface for what gets passed to `mapState`, one clear instance for what comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a correct code to handle this case:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';

interface RootState {
    isOn: boolean;
}

interface Props {
    backgroundColor: string;
}

const mapState = (
    state: RootState,
    props: Props
) => ({
    ...props, // <---- you should add own props here
    isOn: state.isOn,
});

const mapDispatch = {
    toggleOn: () => ({ type: 'TOGGLE_IS_ON' }),
};

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch);

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

const MyComponent = (props: PropsFromRedux) => (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }}>
        <button onClick={props.toggleOn}>
            Toggle is {props.isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
        </button>
    </div>
);

const ConnectedComponent = connector(MyComponent)

const render = <ConnectedComponent backgroundColor="white" /> // ok
```

Since you have added `ownProps` to `mapState`, you should use it.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BvONCAOwaQwBo4BhR5jJAEwAKOMAGc4AXzjZcBIuhgBaInwCuAD3wBuUuQYwkUTOiSIIEGAGUYKfTVJwHcYCIDyDAFxwARmYA2qBm1xHWA9AyM0EyEIUTtHb3QAawBzHBUGPi5faE8RGChQ5KCdegY8uBAUMCsbEwBeOAAKe0c82s8EM0trfVYWhzBhEU9o0VIASjg6gD4m6n64ADplwZiRdgB6DbgAHgV9hTgATwgVOBEAC1PfPjgUPluIAHcGOFXYi4MkBec3XJ6kItfgw%20uJxtpSKVypUwAARZxgGxoC5TOKOGAQZLJfx-JqTGZzOAwI5gJCefAAFRcAHFqQAZACiAH0AJIWJkuABy%20Ak41BEKh8FKPAxUFRwpYMEaMJqvQqVXhIkRMGR4J0xNJcFGIgAYjgQMhVGpUVwmJL%20NqdhqkBBMHRuJLoNMBYxygBZI5ccCMJB6VGNd7DLVDPW4Q3qfGzZrxHZ8YAAN3OxP8dWotC8SVSpwyWRybyGiwzaBSaRzEGyYvE4mmCxjXhUMAxr0YHF8wGLqcDiwxWJxDGrtfijgpmOxJmcNC7wLgAH4CFyeeSXDqdfhgkPHDsNvXG4wazGNnH4zW1ZDXfBTSL%20F7IMw-Q0JRhoI0PTefXpxiVz3AiBkDKidkvc1MlwW9fXgIsS2zECKzqAAiJ4LmAfQ4LgDZZi2OAIESIA)